# What does sample_weight mean in LinearSVC in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

Mathematically, what does sample_weight mean in sklearn.svm.LinearSVC and also svm.SVC? According to what they say in the document, I assume the weights directly changes the C for each sample, i.e., for ith sample the penalty is Cw_i.

Well but I executed the code here
[SVM: Weighted samples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-weighted-samples-py)
Using SVC and LinearSVC (only just change the class to LinearSVC), and it seems that LinearSVC gets sample results regardless of the weights. The developers say that Linear SVC is "less sensitive to sample_weight," but in what sense is it less sensitive (mathematically)?

Another thing - is there any way to use SVC without an intercept? That after all why I use LinearSVC...

Comment: You should maybe ask that on the CrossValidated stack. Not really a question for stackOverflow.